# DST identification for msql

Tags: mysql

I have different users having different timeznoes. Suppose , one user has timezone set as GMT-8:00 (America/Los_Angeles) another has GMT+5:30 (Asia/Kolkata). I have one mysql function which returns current local date time on basis of user.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT(UTC_DATE(),' ',UTC_TIME()),'+00:00','-08:00');
```

Now this is not considering DST timezone. So how to find whether timezone is currently following DST and get date time on basis of that.

Comment: Do you set the current timezone based on the logged in user? If so, please edit your question to include the code which sets the current timezone for the logged in user

Comment: I have one table which stores this information about which user is set to which timezone. From that table you can get two details GMT-8:00 and America/Los_Angeles. And this code is in mysql function which selects and gets offset  GMT-8:00 and executes above query to get date time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702873/mysql-how-to-select-the-utc-offset-and-dst-for-all-timezones?rq=1 might be helpful

Comment: I think it just gets details on whether that timezone follows day light saving mode or not. And not whether it is currently applicable or not.